# Android Bluetooth unclear

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've been reading into the android Bluetooth guide found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html). At this point I understand what the device is and the socket is but I'm a little confused by connection.

I'm trying to make the app a server side listener that simply accepts the first incoming connection request and then send data to it over time. The instructions on how to do this seem very complicated, I was wondering if someone could show me the simplest way to do it.

My main questions are: 
Do I need to create an entirely new activity to handle Bluetooth?
Do all the Bluetooth classes go into a single class?

Sorry for all the questions, just trying to learn here

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example of connecting to a Bluetooth Socket and starting an RFComm transmission, I used debugging in order to find the UUIDs of my device. You do not need a separate class necessarily but I created a separate thread to always be running to look for data being sent over the connection.

```
 BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothSocket mRf, ml2;
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                BlueHelper client = new BlueHelper();
                Af1000Computer = client.findDevice(mBluetoothAdapter);
                if (Af1000Computer != null) {
                    try{

                        ParcelUuid[] uuids = Af1000Computer.getUuids();


                        mRf = Af1000Computer.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
                        //mRf = Af1000Computer.crea
                        //ml2 = new BluetoothSocket(BluetoothSocket.TYPE_L2CAP, -1, true, true, this, 2, null);
                        try {
                            mRf.connect();
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            builder.setMessage("Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage())
                                    .setTitle("Error in creating connection!");
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                        if (mRf.isConnected()){
                            fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.greenaf)));
                            connected = true;
                            slow.setEnabled(true);
                            harvest.setEnabled(true);
                            fast.setEnabled(true);
                            reverse.setEnabled(true);
                            thread = new RfcommThread(mRf);
                            thread.run();
                        }
                       // RfcommThread thread = new RfcommThread(mBluetoothSocket);

                        //View v = findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
                        //thread.run(1, 2, 3);


                    }catch (Exception e){
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setMessage("Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage())
                                .setTitle("Error in creating comm thread!");
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                }
                if (Af1000Computer == null) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage("Cannot find the AF1000 Harvester device! \nHave you connected to the bluetooth device?")
                            .setTitle("Error in Pairing");
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        }
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support BlueHelper
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("This device does not have a bluetooth adapter!")
                    .setTitle("Error in connecting");
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
```